# Why the while function becomes infitine loop? (C Code)

Tags: c, file, bgi

```
    int a=0, x, y, status;
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\input.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no file...");
        return 0;
    }   

    while(1)
    {   
        status = fscanf(file, "%d %d", &x,&y);
        a++;
        if (status == feof(file))
            break;
    }
    
    printf("%d", a);
    fclose(file);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

I wanted to hide that how many times the while function work in a variable and print it then. The while loop becomes infinite loop and i could not solve it.

input.txt file: [input.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCQi7.png)

Comment: Add a minimal `input.txt` file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `if (status == feof(file)` -> `if (status == EOF)`

Comment: `while (fscanf(file, "%d %d", &x,&y) == 2) { ... }` seems a better way to write the loop. Are you really interested in the end of the file or do you just want to process all the data in it that can be processed successfully?

Comment: If `fscanf()` fails to input two integers, then it will return 0 or 1 and the non-matching data will be left in the input buffer. Better to change the loop to `while (fscanf(file, "%d %d", &x,&y) == 2) {}`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've just added the input.txt file.

Comment: @Gwynbleidd next please add text as text. Posting pictures of text is pretty pointless.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'll try it, second. Edit: It worked!, thank you soooo much.

Comment: `feof(file)` only checks for the end-of-file condition. It does not check for an error condition. Theoretically, you could use the function `ferror` to also check for errors. But if you don't care why the read failed (whether it was end-of file or error), then you don't need to use either of these functions. The macro `EOF` (normally defined as `-1`) is returned by `fscanf` irrespective of whether the function failed due to end-of-file or error. In that respect, the name `EOF` is misleading. Or you can just compare with `2` in the first place, as already suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the end of the file comes to `scanf`, it will return `0`, which is different than `feof(file)` (which should be precisely `!=` 0, and so meaning true)

Get used to read manual pages for the library functions.  The `scanf(3)` function returns the actual number of format descriptors matched by the input, and so the number of variables actually read.

You can simply check `if (feof(file))` to test if *after reading something* you got the end of file condition instead.  But think it properly because you'll increment `a` even if any the two variables have not  been read properly.

In my opinion (but is a question of taste) you should better do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

...

int n;
while((n = fscanf("%d%d", &x, &y)) == 2) {
    a++; /* only increment a if both variables have been read */
}
if (n > 0) { /* you ended reading only one variable */
    fprintf(stderr, "Incomplete read at position %d\n", a);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else if (n < 0) { /* fscanf returned an error, check errno */
    fprintf(stderr, "read error: %s (errno = %d)\n",
        strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}  /* else means normal eof */
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```